# I want to validate multiple images with the help of for loop and ASC order Using Jquery Or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, forms, validation

I have an issue in image validation using jQuery Or JavaScript.

Please see code below when I tried myself.

### Briefing

I want to validate multiple images with the help of for loop.

### Issue (Validate Ordering)

When I press  submit button this code has validate images in DESC order (*see image below*) and I want ASC order like `1 field is required...` and then `2 field is required` etc

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function imageValidation(){
    return_var = 'true';

    for(var i=1; i<4; i++){
        if(($('#player-'+i).val()) == ''){
            return_var = i+' field is required';
        }
    }
    alert(return_var);
    return false;

}   
</script>

<form onsubmit="return imageValidation()">
1 <input type="file" id="player-1" name="players[]" /><br />
2 <input type="file" id="player-2" name="players[]" /><br />
3 <input type="file" id="player-3" name="players[]" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

### image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have added a new line of code, just `break;` when first condition match. it will resolve your problem

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function imageValidation(){
    return_var = 'true';

    for(var i=1; i<4; i++){
        if(($('#player-'+i).val()) == ''){
            return_var = i+' field is required';
            break;// break immediately rather wait to complete the loop.
        }
    }
    alert(return_var);
    return false;

}   
</script>

<form onsubmit="return imageValidation()">
1 <input type="file" id="player-1" name="players[]" /><br />
2 <input type="file" id="player-2" name="players[]" /><br />
3 <input type="file" id="player-3" name="players[]" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code:

```
function imageValidation(){
    return_var = 'true';

    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        if(!$.trim( $('#player-'+i).val() )){
            return_var = i+' field is required';
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(return_var);
    return false;
}
```

But With jQuery

```
var return_var = 'true';
$('form input[id^=player]').each(function(index, el) {
  if(!$.trim( this.value)) {
    return_var += (index+1) + ' field is required'; // index is zero based
    break; // if you want to stop execution after invalid found
  }
});
```

so your function will look like

```
function imageValidation(){

   var return_var = 'true';
    $('form input[id^=player]').each(function(index, el) {
      if(!$.trim( this.value)) {
        return_var = (index+1) + ' field is required'; // index is zero based
        break; // if you want to stop execution after invalid found
      }
    });
    alert(return_var);
    return false;
}
```